# How do quantum computers encode a string?

Tags: quantum-state

New to quantum computing.

How do quantum computers represent a string at the hardware level?

For example, if Classical computers wanted to encode "Hello world!", they would use UTF-8 to represent "H" as 01001000, "e" as 01100101, and so on.

Can qubits store information like this? Is there a UTF-8 equivalent for quantum computers?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, registers of qubits could store strings in the UTF-8 format or the ASCII format or ISO-8859-1 format, or whatever format is convenient.

Indeed a key feature distinguishing a quantum encoding from a classical encoding would be that you could encode a register of qubits into a superposition of strings.  For example you can have a register in a superposition such as:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\big(|\text{Hello World!}\rangle-|\text{Goodbye World!}\rangle\big).$$

If each character is 8 bits long, then you could use UTF-8 to represent 'H' as $|01001000\rangle$, to represent 'e' as $|01001000\rangle$, ... to represent 'G' as $|01000111\rangle$, 'o' as $|01101111\rangle$, etc.  So you would have a register of qubits such as:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\big(|0100100001001000\cdots\rangle-|0100011101101111\cdots\rangle\big).$$

To be honest, however, in the foreseeable future most quantum algorithms probably won't treat data as strings of characters, as mostly we want our quantum algorithms to work on numbers (integers) - which would likely be represented in [signed binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations), or perhaps in some [Gray encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).  Another aspect of encoding that we worry about now is the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the numbers so encoded, which is implementation-dependent.